Fetching all signatures of a address
getSignaturesForAddress fetches max 1000 signatures at once, and to fetch all signatures of a particular address, this process becomes sequencial, is there any way to parallelize fetching?

It's not really possible unfortunately, the getSignaturesForAddress entrypoint also allows a before parameter, where all fetched signatures will be from before the given one, but you need to know that signature in order to specify it, which requires the previous call to getSignaturesForAddress.
You can only parallelize it if you somehow know those transaction signatures beforehand.
More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress

what if we break down in range of slots, and parallelize to some extent?

If you look at the parameters in getSignaturesForAddress, you'll see that you can't provide a slot range, only signatures
